# Zabbix-proxy on the same server that Zabbix-server

Tags: zabbix

I installed a zabbix-server and a zabbix-proxy on the same server, a debian 7.6
But I can't run zabbix-proxy on a passive mode, here is the issue :

```
listener failed: zbx_tcp_listen() fatal error: unable to serve on any address [[-]:10051]
```

Here is my netstat

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10050           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2142/zabbix_agentd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10051           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      55825/zabbix_server
```

Because my zabbix-proxy need to be on a passive mode, I can not change his port. Any way to force this changing or any fix to handle this case ?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reconfigure `ListenPort` of Zabbix server and then just use that new Zabbix server port in other settings (agents, proxies, senders, ...).

Doc: https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/appendix/config/zabbix_server

Comment: Okay, I forgot to say that I'm on Zabbix 2.4 and it seems that I can not configure a port in passive mode...
But thanks anyway

Comment: Sorry for my answer, your were right, I mixed it with ServerPort